# control on am/pm format in android app

Tags: android, time-format

trying to show/hide image i created to show the sun when the time is am and show the moon when the time is pm

i tried 2 codes but its show the pm image only in both of the am/pm format

code number one

```
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.isSet(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mCalendar.isSet(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if (mCalendar.get(Calendar.AM_am) == Calendar.AM)
    image_am.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    image_pm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (mCalendar.get(Calendar.PM_pm) == Calendar.PM)
     image_pm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     image_am.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yy h:m:s a");
    String strdate1 = sdf1.format(mCalendar.getTime());
```

code number two

```
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.isSet(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mCalendar.isSet(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if (mCalendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
      AM_PM= R.drawable.sun;
    if (mCalendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
        AM_PM= R.drawable.moon;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yy h:m:s a");
    String strdate1 = sdf1.format(mCalendar.getTime());
    Imageview.setBackgroundResource(AM_PM);
```

is there is any way to make any of those codes show and hide the sun/moon image in am/pm format because its only show the pm (moon) image only ?

Comment: where you calling this function and for checking am and pm r you changing system date?

Comment: calling it from the mainactivity and i checking for am and pm but i dont show any numbers i hide every thing only make this code show my image in am / pm ...